# Efficient multiplication of super-size matrices in matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I don't have enough memory to simply create diagonal matrix D x D, getting an 'out of memory' error.
Instead of performing M x D x D operations in the first multiplication, I do M x D operations, but still my code takes ages to run.

Can anybody find a more effective way to multiply these matrices in matlab?

```
D=20000
M=25

A = floor(rand(D,M)*10);
B = floor(rand(1,M)*10);


for i=1:D
 for j=1:M
  result(i,j) = A(i,j) * B(1,j);
 end
end


manual = result * A';
auto = A*diag(B)*A';
isequal(manual,auto)
```

Comment: You should ask this on Stackoverflow. Your code takes ages since you use loops and Matlab is interpreted. In Matlab everything must be vectorized.

Comment: This was true of ancient versions, but these days matlab has a JIT compiler which is pretty good at optimizing loops. Vectorization doesn't actually provide much benefit, other than having cleaner code by expressing the problem at a higher level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/248346). They suggest one of the following solutions:

```
A*bsxfun(@times,diag(D),A')
```

OR

```
A*sparse(D)*A'
```

Matlab is an interpreted language and so explicit loops are very slow (even though in the latest version there's supposedly in-place compilation). So everything must be vectorized.

As an aside, did you search the internet at all? It took Google 0.16s to come up with that web page as the first result (for *matlab multiplying by a diagonal matrix*).

Comment: thanks for that, Google's inverted indexes can't be beaten by anybody, it's 5am here, I'm just about to collapse

Comment: @matcheek: If you believe Yuval's answer was helpful, it would be courteous of you to click the check mark on the left side of Yuval's answer.

Comment: it's very helpful, don't have much privileges here, can't upvote,  I can only accept the answer, which I usually do after I test it. Investigating all the intricacies now